# Ninject - overloads for WithConstructorArgument behave weird

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

I have the following code:

```
namespace Test.Ninject.ConstructorArgumentBug
{

public class ClassA
{
    private readonly IDependecy _dependecy;

    public ClassA(IDependecy dependecy)
    {
        _dependecy = dependecy;
    }
}

public interface IDependecy
{
}

public class ConcreteDependency : IDependecy
{
    private readonly string _arg;

    public ConcreteDependency(string arg)
    {
        _arg = arg;
    }
}

public class Tests
{
    [Test]
    public void Test1()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Bind<IDependecy>()
            .To<ConcreteDependency>()
            .WhenInjectedInto<ClassA>()
            .WithConstructorArgument(new ConstructorArgument("arg", "test"));

        var classA = kernel.Get<ClassA>();
        Assert.IsNotNull(classA);
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test2()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Bind<IDependecy>()
            .To<ConcreteDependency>()
            .WhenInjectedInto<ClassA>()
            .WithConstructorArgument("arg", "test");

        var classA = kernel.Get<ClassA>();
        Assert.IsNotNull(classA);
    }
}
}
```

The Test1 doesn't work, but the Test2 does, and I believe they should behave the same. It looks like a bug to me. For some reason the first test cannot resolve dependency with the following error:

> Ninject.ActivationException : Error activating string
>   No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.
>   Activation path:
>     3) Injection of dependency string into parameter arg of constructor of type ConcreteDependency
>     2) Injection of dependency IDependecy into parameter dependecy of constructor of type ClassA
>     1) Request for ClassA

I guess if the first test fails the second should fail too. Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Test1`, the `WithConstructorArgument` method that you are invoking has the following signature:

```
IBindingWithOrOnSyntax<T> WithConstructorArgument<TValue>(TValue value);
```

Here is what the documentation says about this method (you get this on IntelliSense):

> Indicates that the specified constructor argument should be overridden with the specified value.

And here is the documentation for `TValue`:

> Specifies the argument type to override

And here is the documentation for `value`:

> The value for the argument

So, this line:

```
.WithConstructorArgument(new ConstructorArgument("arg", "test"));
```

Which is equivalent to (C# automatically infers `TValue`):

```
.WithConstructorArgument<ConstructorArgument>(new ConstructorArgument("arg", "test"));
```

is telling NInject that the constructor of `ConcreteDependency` has a parameter of type `ConstructorArgument`, where in fact it has a parameter of type `string`.

So you should change it to

```
.WithConstructorArgument<string>("test");
```

Or simpler:

```
.WithConstructorArgument("test");
```

Please note that there is no overload of `WithConstructorArgument` that has a parameter of type `ConstructorArgument`.

However, there is another method called `WithParameter` that takes in an `IParameter`.

Since `ConstructorArgument` implements `IParameter`, you can use this method to specify the constructor argument via `ConstructorArgument` like this:

```
kernel.Bind<IDependecy>()
    .To<ConcreteDependency>()
    .WhenInjectedInto<ClassA>()
    .WithParameter(new ConstructorArgument("arg", "test"));
```